# Sphere in homogenou magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I have to find out the magnetic dipole moment of sphere in homogenou magnetic field in the limit $\mu_r\rightarrow+\infty$.

I don't know what does the condition $\mu_r\rightarrow+\infty$ mean. Does it mean, that the field inside the sphere will be 0 because it won't let any field in? In that case should I determine the surface currents on the sphere and determine the dipole moment from that?

Comment: $\mu\rightarrow\infty $ means that the sphere is a perfect magnetic conductor.  Look at amperes law in regard with this.